# Using multiple layout in Yii

Tags: html, tabs, yii

My Yii application has a particular section called 'Edit Profile' . It's a pretty data heavy section in the way a lot of data is pulled from db for this one .

However the problem is that I have tab pagination in this section . Because only this section uses tabs on the website I did not include the related CSS/Javascript files in the main layout header .These have been referenced in the view file itself . Because of this the tabs takes time to show up and the tab titles appear as a list first (for a second or two) and then get distributed into tabs with the correct UI . This is of course unacceptable behaviour . Is there any way to selectively include related js/css files into the header tag for this particular view or should I include it in main layhout file even though it won't be used in a lot of other places on the website thus possibly slowing down other pages .

Comment: I think you could perhaps use javascript and somehow tell your page to only be displayed when all the scripts have been run. You could `hide` everything before all your scripts get executed and then, after all your scripts have run, `show` your page

Comment: But that would be worse off , don't you think ? The user won't see anything appear on the page for a considerable time (~2-3 seconds)

Comment: I don't know. Perhaps you could just hide whatever widget you're having trouble with (rather than the whole page). It happens to me sometimes.. pisses me off too hehehe

Comment: Ah well , it is not a widget .It is the reason for having the page . So cannot hide it .

Comment: Well then I think you could place an `if` in the main.php layout file and do some kind of testing like `$this->controller == 'controllerName'` or something like that.. I'm almost sure you can access the controller name and/or the view name from within the layout file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specify the position for the file.

In your view where you are including the js or css :

```
// for js
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile('url_of_file',CClientScript::POS_HEAD);

// for css
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile('url_of_file');
```

Recommended documentation: [`registerScriptFile()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#registerScriptFile-detail) , and [`registerCssFile()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#registerCssFile-detail)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own layout in the layouts folder , where u can include all the required jquery scripts and css. U can then call your layout in the controller.

```
public function actionDoSomething(){
$this->layout = 'mylayout';
$this->render('myview');
}
```